# How to send SOAP requests in php

Tags: php, python, soap, tornado

Okay so I have a Python server running and I've been using "suds" as a client side which has been surprisingly easy, when I tried to run a similar code in PHP I got very confused since I was a beginner with it?

```
from suds.client import Client

url = 'http://localhost:8080/FlightService?wsdl'
client = Client(url=url)
output = client.service.getFlightList("dxb","ksa")
print(output)
```

is there something with this ease in php or can anyone show me a sample code which would return the same result?

Considering the server receives this:

```
class Input(complextypes.ComplexType):
    dpt = str 
    arr = str
```

and returns a list of flights

```
class flight(complextypes.ComplexType):
    id    = int
    dpt  = str
    arr  = str
    price = float
    date = str
    tickets = int
```

this is the webservice:

```
@webservice(_params=Input,_returns=[flight])
def getFlightList(self, input):
```

my PHP segment:

```
<?php   
    $url = 'http://172.27.130.98:8080/FlightService?wsdl';
    $client = new SoapClient($url);
    echo("Hello!");
    $result = $client->bookFlight("dxb","ksa");
    $result2 = $client->handle();
    echo($result);
    echo($result2);
?>
```

PHP Error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [HTTP] Error Fetching http headers in C:\wamp\www\soap\soap.php:6 Stack trace: #0 [internal function]: SoapClient->__doRequest('<?xml version="...', 'http://172.27.1...', 'http://172.27.1...', 1, 0) #1 C:\wamp\www\soap\soap.php(6): SoapClient->__call('getFlightList', Array) #2 C:\wamp\www\soap\soap.php(6): SoapClient->getFlightList('dxb', 'ksa') #3 {main} thrown in C:\wamp\www\soap\soap.php on line 6
```

Exception info:

```
SoapFault Object ( [message:protected] => Error Fetching http headers [string:Exception:private] => [code:protected] => 0 [file:protected] => C:\wamp\www\soap\soap.php [line:protected] => 6 [trace:Exception:private] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [function] => __doRequest [class] => SoapClient [type] => -> [args] => Array ( [0] => ksa [1] => http://172.27.130.98:8080/FlightService [2] => http://172.27.130.98:8080/FlightService/getFlightList [3] => 1 [4] => 0 ) ) [1] => Array ( [file] => C:\wamp\www\soap\soap.php [line] => 6 [function] => __call [class] => SoapClient [type] => -> [args] => Array ( [0] => getFlightList [1] => Array ( [0] => dxb [1] => ksa ) ) ) [2] => Array ( [file] => C:\wamp\www\soap\soap.php [line] => 6 [function] => getFlightList [class] => SoapClient [type] => -> [args] => Array ( [0] => dxb [1] => ksa ) ) ) [previous:Exception:private] => [faultstring] => Error Fetching http headers [faultcode] => HTTP [xdebug_message] => ( ! ) SoapFault: Error Fetching http headers in C:\wamp\www\soap\soap.php on line 6 Call Stack #TimeMemoryFunctionLocation 10.0006243160{main}( )..\soap.php:0 20.0758264872getFlightList ( )..\soap.php:6 30.0758265336__call ( )..\soap.php:6 )
```

Comment: You want SoapClient. It's reasonably straightforward.

Comment: I don't know Python, but that all looks fairly simple, and trivial to translate to PHP's SoapClient. Can you show us the PHP code you got stuck with?

Comment: @JoelHinz i'm really confused using soapClient in php could you show me the simple equivalent of my python code if you don't mind? i couldn't really get my head around using it as am new to SOAP and PHP, as you notice python only used 3 lines of code to send a request without specifying the received arguements

Comment: @IMSoP this is my code http://codeshare.io/ye6to not connecting correctly to server it's not even able to read the "dpt" and "arr" but a connection is made, i'm very new at php

Comment: @Newbie Please [edit] the question to include that code and the **exact** problem or error you encountered, since that's much more important to knowing how to help you than seeing all your Python code.

Comment: @IMSoP added my code and exception

Comment: Aha, now we have something to work with; next time, describe the problem fully in the first place, and save everyone some time. A couple of things you can do to get extra information: put `try {` before and `} catch ( SoapFault $e ) { print_r($e); }` around your code to see the full exception details; and try using [`__getLastRequest`](http://php.net/manual/en/soapclient.getlastrequest.php) to see the generated XML and compare it with what your successful Python generates.

Comment: By the way `echo` in PHP is a keyword not a function (doesn't need brackets) and only outputs scalar values. For arrays and objects, you can use the print_r(), var_dump(), or var_export() functions.

Comment: @IMSoP result of printing the exception

Comment: @IMSoP i turned it into a dictionary or a list and it worked now all i have to is extract data from the object, resulting in "Fatal error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array in C:\wamp\www\soap\soap.php on line 14"

Comment: @IMSoP thanks for your feedback, you helped me a lot with debugging the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this solution worked for me, i instantiated an associative array with the name of variables i'm expecting at server side then used var_dump to get the result of the output

```
<?php   
    $url = 'http://172.27.130.98:8080/FlightService?wsdl';
    $client = new SoapClient($url);
    echo("Hello!");
    $trip["dpt"] = "dxb";
    $trip["arr"] = "krt";
try{    $output = $client->getFlightList($trip);
    }
    catch(soapFault $e)
    {
    print_r($e);
    }
    var_dump($output);
?>
```

Comment: Glad you got it working. Just so you know, you can create the array without making an intermediate variable: `$client->getFlightList(['dpt' => 'dxb', 'arr' => 'krt']);`

Comment: @IMSoP thank you very much, sorry that i dragged an almost useless python code into this but i wanted to explain my thoughts :)